# Jackson jsonproperty name when there are multiple instances of the same object

Tags: java, jackson

Take this example:

```
class Car {
    Door leftDoor;
    Door rightDoor;

    Door getLeftDoor();
    Door getRightDoor();
}

class Door {
    String getType();
}
```

The goal is to have this json:

```
{
    "Door.lefttype": "A",
    "Door.righttype": "B"
}
```

I have the object mapper configured that only things with @JsonProperty are converted to Json.

If I only had one door, I could simply put `@JsonProperty("door.type")` on `String getDoorType()`. But since there are multiple instances of the same type I can't put the annotation on the last class. Furthermore, I need @JsonUnwrapped because I don't want it to make a hierarchy in the json. I want this:

```
door.lefttype: "A"
```

instead of

```
door: {
    lefttype: "A"
}
```

What I have so far (I'm using interfaces + mixins since I don't have access to the classes directly):

```
public interface CarMixin {
    @JsonProperty
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Door getLeftDoor();

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonUnwrapped
    Door getRightDoor();
}

public interface DoorMixIn {
    @JsonProperty
    String getType();
}
```

I need the exact names, so this doesn't suffice. I need to use named JsonProperties

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have the same understanding of mixin as you do, and I must say I'm little unclear what is the extend of your limitation in modifying existing classes, but I would think something along the following lines might help:

```
class Car {
   Door leftDoor ;
   Door rightDoor ;

   @JsonProperty("Door.lefttype")
   String leftType() {
        return leftDoor.getType() ;
   }

   @JsonProperty("Door.righttype")
   String leftType() {
        return rightDoor.getType() ;
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the classes since I just import them (they're not mine). Which means I use mixins to add the Jackson tags